# How to pass Ransack parameters to the path for test a page on Rails Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a view `article/index` well covered with tests. After improving the application, we added a separate search form and now you can get to the index page only if you pass it parameters from the search form. All tests for the index have failed because of this new `search_index` form.

Is there an easy way to pass parameters to `ArticlePage.new` at the very beginning to make the tests work again?

We use Ransack to find records. That is, to get to the index page, I need to pass at least one search parameter.Example of parameters:

`http://localhost:3000/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bperson_id%5D=&q%5Bboard_id%5D=`

Controller:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      redirect_to search_index_articles_path if current_user.admin? && params[:q].nil?
      @articles = search_results
   end
end
```

RSpec file:

```rb
# spec/features/tests/articles/article_spec.rb

RSpec.feature 'Articles navigation', type: :system, js: true do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:article_page) { Articles::ArticlePage.new }

  before do
    sign_in(user, scope: :user)
    article_page.visit_page
  end

  scenario 'title input is correct' do
    expect(find_field('Title').value).to eq ''
  end
end
```

```rb
# spec/fearures/pages/articles/article_page.rb
require 'features/pages/application_page'

module Articles
  class ArticlePage < ApplicationPage
    def visit_page
      visit articles_path( q: {person_id: 'John Doe' } )
    end
  end
end
```

I try to pass Ransack parameters to the `articles_path` but it is not correct and in the result on the page no one items found.

Comment: This code is really strange. In capybara you would normally use the `visit` method to change the location of the client. Since it only does get requests you add parameters by adding query string parameters. Other types of requests are done by filling in forms or clicking buttons with js handlers. What the heck is `Articles::ArticlePage`? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/4-0/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec

Comment: before { sign_in(user, scope: :user); visit('/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bperson_id%5D=&q%5Bboard_id%5D=')}.  should be ok, I guess

Comment: @dom you don't need to manually build the query string. `visit('/articles', params: { q: 'Hello World', foo: 1, bar: 2 })` whenever someone manually does this kind of thing its a good recipe for double encoding.

Comment: Thanks @max for answer. Yes, we have `visit` inside pages folder it is called through `visit_page`, I update info. Also we use Ransack for searching articles, so I need to pass one of the parameters it needs, for example `person_id`.

Comment: Don't pass the parameters manually, [fill in and submit the form](https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master#Interacting_with_forms). Then the test will continue to work if small details of the form change, and it will test that the form works. If you just want to test the controller, [test the controller directly](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers).

Comment: Oh yes, you guys right, all i need is after visit my new search_index page click on `Search` button, so I do it like this: ` tracking_page.visit_page;  tracking_page.search;` and add the search method to pages file `def search; click_on 'Search'; end`